# R: debugging code from emacs using ess-tracebug?

Tags: debugging, r, emacs, ess

I want to use interactive debugging of R code in emacs, and found about ess-tracebug, but can't get it to work. I did the following:

1. Installed `ess-tracebug`
2. Started execution of an R script with ESS `C-c C-n`
3. Set up a breakpoint, now if I try to do `M-c c`, says "Debugging is not active"

Here is what I added to my `~/.emacs` file:

```
(load "/home/user/ess/ess-5.13/lisp/ess-site")
(ess-toggle-underscore nil)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/user/emacs/")
(require 'ess-tracebug)
(add-hook 'ess-post-run-hook 'ess-tracebug t)
(define-key ess-mode-map "\M-]" 'next-error)
(define-key ess-mode-map "\M-[" 'previous-error)
(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map "\M-]" 'next-error-no-select)
(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map "\M-[" 'previous-error-no-select)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are running `R` in an Emacs buffer and you have your script in another buffer. In order to debug with `ess-tracebug` you must type `M-x ess-tracebug` to start the actual tracebug session.

This should do the job.

Comment: Yes that's exactly right, as homepage also says you can activate ess-tracebug every time R session starts with `(add-hook 'ess-post-run-hook 'ess-tracebug)`